# Jquery event is not defined - get attribute of the clicked element even

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, attributes

I have a "default template" and i load some views on body (with codeigniter)

in one of these views, i have a table that have some td like this:

```
<td data-target="#VRModal" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal"><a href="#">Details</a></td>
```

on the bottom of this view i have a bootstrap modal

```
<div id="VRModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;<span class="sr-only">Close</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Details</h4>
        </div>

        <div id="orderDetails" class="modal-body"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
                $('#VRModal').modal({
                keyboard: true,
                backdrop: "static",
                show:false

            }).on('show.bs.modal', function(){
                var id = $(event.target).closest('td').data('data-id');
                var url = '<?= site_url() ?>/' + '<?= $this->uri->uri_string() ?>/'+id;
                $.ajax({                        url: url,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $('#orderDetails').html(html)
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Its all working, except for the line of 'var id'

Got this error on console:

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
var id = $(event.target).closest('td').attr('data-id');
```

**Update:**
It seems your code has some syntax error too.
Try this as complete code:

```
$('#VRModal').modal({
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: "static",
    show:false
});

$('#VRModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).closest('td').attr('data-id');
    alert(id);
    var url = '<?= site_url() ?>/' + '<?= $this->uri->uri_string() ?>/'+id;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html)
        {
            $('#orderDetails').html(html)
        }
    });
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7awk08v/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#VRModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
    var id = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
    // other code
})
```

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c7hsth35/